# SVG image not changing when clicking on element using IOS or other mobile devices. Works fine on PC / Mac

Tags: css, svg, focus, background-image, anchor

When using Safari or any mobile device, clicking on the links (a tags) the :focus background-image does not load.

It works fine on Chrome, Opera, Firefox on Mac and PC.

Using Bootstrap 4

I have attached pictures to illustrate a little better.

Structure:

ul

-li

--a (SVG is attached to a tag via CSS class)

---span

```html
<div class="row" style="margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <h1 class="heading-center">WHAT WE OFFER</h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <ul
                class="nav nav-pills mb-3 justify-content-center"
                id="pills-tab"
                role="tablist"
              >
                <li class="nav-item anchor">
                  <a
                    href="#pills-businesses"
                    aria-selected="false"
                    data-toggle="pill"
                    class="businesses offer"
                    ><span>BUSINESSES</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                ...some code omitted...
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
          </div>
```

```
.poi {
  font-family: "akrobatbold";
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #282828;
}

.anchor {
  padding: 15px 45px 15px 45px;
  font-family: "akrobatbold";
}

a.offer {
  display: block;
  outline: none !important;
  border: #fff;
  color: #282828;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

a.offer:focus {
  font-family: "akrobatblack";
}

a.offer span {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.businesses {
  width: 100px;
  height: 85px;
  background-image: url("/assets/sketch/businessess-outline-notext.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.businesses:focus {
  background-image: url("/assets/sketch/businessess-solid-notext.svg");
}
.businesses:hover {
  color: inherit;
}

...some code omitted...
```

Any ideas what I could do to make it work?

[image: Unselected]
[image: Selected]

Comment: Please change the `<a>` with `<input type="text"` and it will work in Safari too. [Bug 22261 - Clicking on a non-text input element does not give it focus](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22261)

Comment: Ok that kind off worked.  If I disable the input, then the change of svg doesnt happen.  Currently it works like a standard text input with an SVG inside.